# Deprecated getch() - switching to recommended by compiler _getch() still causes problems

Tags: c++, fstream, getch

I would really need your help on this one and I hope I'll get some clue about my compiler error.

The problematic piece of my code:

```
char user_ch;
do {
        user_ch=_getch(); // i changed it from getch() to fix the previous error, didn't help it seems
        switch (user_ch) {
            case '1': response='1'; break;
            case '3': response='3';
        }
} while (response!='1'||response!='3');
```

Compiler error (what's peculiar it's 'build' error instead of 'debug' error):

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

Compiler refers to this piece of code in fstream file:

```
private:
_Myfb _Filebuffer;  // the file buffer
};
```

As someone pointed out I'm posting my usage of fstream functions and objects.
**My functions parsing settings.txt file**

```
bool read_bool(ifstream file, int verse) {
string temp_var;
for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
    getline(file, temp_var);
if (temp_var=="true") return true;
else return false; }

int read_int(ifstream file, int verse) {
string temp_var;
for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
    getline(file, temp_var);
return stoi(temp_var); }

t_direction read_t_dir(ifstream file, int verse) {
char temp_var;
for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
file.get(temp_var);
t_direction pre_return;
switch (temp_var) {
    case '1': pre_return=to_mother; break;
    case '2': pre_return=to_foreign; break;
    case '3': pre_return=rndom;
}
return pre_return; }

string read_string(ifstream file, int verse) {
string temp_var;
for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
    getline(file, temp_var);
return temp_var; }

size_t lines_count(ifstream if_file) {
size_t a=0;
string temp_str;
while (getline(if_file, temp_str)) 
    ++a;
return a; }

bool add_mistake(ofstream file, string mistake, string to_trans, string target) {
file << "Original: " << to_trans << "\nShould be: " << target;
file << "\nYour response: " << mistake;
file << "\n---------------------\n";
return true; }
```

**For error-security sake i've never opened or closed fstream object inside a function**.

```
// stream from file and tokenize
// SYNTAX FOR FILE (each line): word,word>word,word,word
words_input.open(FILE_NAME);
string buffer_line, token;
for (size_t i; i<number_of_lines; i++) {
    getline(words_input, buffer_line);
    istringstream language_split(buffer_line);
    vector<string> container(2);
    while (getline(language_split, token, '>')) // split languages
        container.push_back(token); // hard coded to ignore possible elements 3, 4, 5...
    istringstream synonym_source_split(container.at(0));
    while (getline(synonym_source_split, token, ',')) // first language synonyms
        source_words[i].push_back(token);
    istringstream synonym_target_split(container.at(1));
    while (getline(synonym_target_split, token, ',')) // second language synonyms
        target_words[i].push_back(token);
}
words_input.close();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is the error message you'd get if you tried to copy an `ostream` or `fstream` object. The error is not in the code that you're showing above. Can you post more code for context?

Comment: Actually `_getch()` isn't portable, while [`std::getc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) is.

Comment: My code is too large and I cannot really deduce where can be more context since those variables and getch() function are... like... isolated inside the do{}

Comment: I am almost positive this has nothing to do with `_getch()` or `getch()`. Are you using `fstream`, `ifstream`, `ofstream`, or `stringstream` anywhere in your code?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What is `_getch()` defined as in your case?

Comment: @templatetypedef i've edited my post for context

Comment: `while (response!='1'||response!='3')` This will loop forever. No matter what value it is, it can't be both `1` and `3`, therefore it must be the case that it's not `1` or it's not `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this part of the code:

```
string read_string(ifstream file, int verse) {
    string temp_var;
    for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
        getline(file, temp_var);
    return temp_var;
}

size_t lines_count(ifstream if_file) {
    size_t a=0;
    string temp_str;
    while (getline(if_file, temp_str)) 
        ++a;
    return a;
}
```

Both of these functions take as input a parameter of type `ifstream`. Since you're not taking in the `ifstream` by reference, when you call this function, C++ will try to initialize `if_file` to a copy of the `ifstream` that you passed in as a parameter. This isn't allowed, since `ifstream`s can't be copied. Unfortunately, you tend to get garbage error messages like the one you showed above instead of something more useful in this case.

To fix this, change your code so that you take the parameters by reference:

```
string read_string(ifstream& file, int verse) {
    string temp_var;
    for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
        getline(file, temp_var);
    return temp_var;
}

size_t lines_count(ifstream& if_file) {
    size_t a=0;
    string temp_str;
    while (getline(if_file, temp_str)) 
        ++a;
    return a;
}
```

That said, there are likely other errors in your code. I would strongly recommend commenting your code as you go and testing pieces incrementally, since as written the code is pretty tough to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what's so tough in my code for instance? I try to follow every programmer etiquete as far as I know.

Comment: @TheTobruk A few things come to mind. First, you don't seem to be indenting your code, which makes it visually difficult for me to find the start or end of functions. You're also putting your close curly braces for functions at the end of the last line of the function, which you're doing consistently (good!) but doesn't seem to follow an established convention (less good). Also, your functions don't have any comments on them, which makes it hard to read. I think it might be a good idea to get into the habit of addressing these, though from a functionality perspective it's not wrong.

Comment: The error is still there unfortunately. I've replaced every function using either ofstream or ifstream to take them as reference but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @TheTobruk Have you gone through the code and consistently changed your functions taking `ifstream`s to take `ifstream&`s? I see a few more functions in the code with this error that I missed the first time around.

Comment: Yes I thought about that too.

Comment: @TheTobruk You may want to post a follow-up question with your updated code and the error message you're getting now. If you're still getting the same error message, it likely means that you're making the same error somewhere else in the code. If you're not getting this error message - or if you're getting a runtime error rather than a compile error - you should post a new question with that information so that we can try to help diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: My code. [http://paste.ofcode.org/T3ujisYNMtffcWHBskwjTe](http://paste.ofcode.org/T3ujisYNMtffcWHBskwjTe) Could someone take a closer look at it? I'll appreciate it so badly.

Comment: @TheTobruk You should post this as a separate question. Asking someone to review your code in a comment is unlikely to attract attention. (I have to head out to a meeting soon, so if you only post this here, chances are no one will see it.)